# Static ipv6 on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ipv6, ipv4

I need to create a virtual machine with Ubuntu, setting static IPV4 and IPV6 address. It is working, however, I always have an extra IPV6 address, that I want to get rid of.

I set everything in etc/network/interfaces and only added a site-local ipv6

The ipv4 address is **192.168.100.10** and the ipv6 should be the a site-local correspondence to ipv4. What I see in ifconfig is **fec0::c0a8:640a/124** which I think is correct (fix me if I'm wrong), but I also see a second IPV6: **fe80::a00:27ff:fec6:6b97/64**

Where does this second address come from? How can I get rid of it?

Comment: It's the _first_ address you should get rid of.

Answer (score 3):

The first address (`fec0::c0a8:640a/124`) is a deprecated site-local address that should not be used anymore. Also in almost all circumstances the prefix length should be /64. Take a look at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4193 about which addresses to use on private networks that are not connected to the internet.

The second address (`fe80::a00:27ff:fec6:6b97/64`) is a link-local address. Every IPv6 interface must have one, it's part of how the protocol works. It can only be used to communicate with other systems on the same LAN (link-local: only usable on the directly connected link). While this might seem very restricted at first, it makes things like neighbour-discovery, finding default gateways, host configuration with DHCPv6, finding local services on the LAN etc a lot easier and cleaner to implement.

Your configuration is perfectly normal. Every IPv6 interface has at least one link-local address in addition to other (routable) addresses. Having multiple addresses per interface is the norm for IPv6.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that site-local addresses are deprecated, but it was required by a university demo project. It's not gonna be used for an actual machine, just a virtual machine and only for a demo.
I didn't know that a link-local address is mandatory.

Comment: Can you please confirm that fec0::c0a8:640a/124 is a correct transcription of 192.168.100.10?

Comment: No, there is no connection between IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, so no transcription is possible, and fec0::/12 is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Correct your assignment, tell your professor the addresses they make you use are invalid, and switch to ULA.

Comment: Static address in IPv6 is just a useless idea from last century internet: ULA plus EUI64 are so much better!  These are the addresses you can just calculate before you have touched the machine. Do not add static addresses - use one of the predictable existing ones! Example local: ULA with prefix from router. Example WAN-Internet: Prefix Delegation + EUI64 works perfect. Stop thinking v4 - IPv6 is the predictable solution without bloated overhead and dodgy applications.